# How do I mount the CentOS 7 ISO and add it as a yum repository

Tags: centos7, repository

How do I mount the CentOS 7 ISO and add it as a yum repository?

The places I search say to look for a `media.repo` underneath the mounted ISO, but there is no such file.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The repo file is already present on your installed CentOS system, as `/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Media.repo`.

```
[root@localhost ~]# cat /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Media.repo 
# CentOS-Media.repo
#
#  This repo can be used with mounted DVD media, verify the mount point for
#  CentOS-7.  You can use this repo and yum to install items directly off the
#  DVD ISO that we release.
#
# To use this repo, put in your DVD and use it with the other repos too:
#  yum --enablerepo=c7-media [command]
#  
# or for ONLY the media repo, do this:
#
#  yum --disablerepo=\* --enablerepo=c7-media [command]

[c7-media]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Media
baseurl=file:///media/CentOS/
        file:///media/cdrom/
        file:///media/cdrecorder/
gpgcheck=1
enabled=0
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-7
```

Mount the ISO image at one of the given locations, or modify the file appropriately, then enable it as instructed.

Answer (score 3):

Mount the iso

```
mount -o loop,ro centos7.iso /mnt/centos7-iso
```

Create this file `/etc/yum.repos.d/repo.repo`

```
[centos7-Server]
name=ServerFault Answer
baseurl=file:///mnt/centos7-iso
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-7
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
```

Then check if it worked with

```
yum list
```

Answer (score 0):

**Installing CentOS packages from CentOS DVD iso on VirtualBox**

Insert CentOS DVD image in VM:

```
Devices->Optical drives->CentOS-8.5.2111-x86_64-dvd1.iso
```

DVD will be visible at following location:

```
/run/media/user/CentOS-8-5-2111-x86_64-dvd/
```

Login as root:

```
su root
```

Create Directory /media/CentOS

```
mkdir /media/CentOS
```

Run following commands to mount package repositories under /media/CentOS:

```
$> ln -s /run/media/user/CentOS-8-5-2111-x86_64-dvd/BaseOS/ /media/CentOS
$> ln -s /run/media/user/CentOS-8-5-2111-x86_64-dvd/AppStream /media/CentOS

$> ls /media/CentOS/  
AppStream BaseOS
```

Check status of repositories using command:

```
$> yum repolist all
```

Enable our media repos:

```
$> yum config-manager --enable=media-appstream
$> yum config-manager --enable=media-baseos
```

Disable all other repos:

```
$> yum config-manager --disable=[repoid]
```

Run following command and you will see all available packages:

```
$> yum list
```

Install package using command:

```
$> yum install <package-name>
```